# mono and passing on unicode strings

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, mono

I'm embedding mono in an application of mine but i have issues with mono's string conversion.

C++ code:

```
static inline void p_Print(MonoString *str) {
    cout << "UTF8: " << mono_string_to_utf8(str) << endl;
    wcout << "UTF16: " << ((wchar_t*)mono_string_to_utf16(str)) << endl;
}

//...

mono_add_internal_call("SampSharp.GameMode.Natives.Native::Print", (void *)p_Print);
```

C# code:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern void Print(string msg);

//...

Print("characters like \u00D6 are working? (should be an O with \" above it)");
```

output:

```
UTF8: characters like ├û are working? (should be an O with " above it)
UTF16: characters like Í are working? (should be an O with " above it)
```

As you can see, the output is not quite what it should print, it should be printing "characters like Ö are working? (should be an O with " above it)", but neither mono_string_to_utf8 or _to_utf16 does what it should do.

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What Operating System are you using and are you running your program from some command-line interface?

Comment: If this happens to be cmd.exe on Windows, it doesn't support unicode. You can try setting codepage on it to one that supports symbols you're trying to print, but to be sure, redirect output into text file, that should give correct results (well, unless the problem is somewhere else ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the info about consoles. Yet i use _to_utf8 somewhere else as well and it displays it elsewhere. When i send to the display(not in console, elsewhere) \u00D6 directly from C++ it shows the right character, but calling the same function from C#/mono it shows ├û. It must be an issue with _to_utf8 then.

Comment: @ikkentim It works for me in Linux (I can show you an example if you wish) I bet you have encoding problems. You should find out what encoding are you using while compiling and what encoding the "display" thing requires.

Comment: @Gooseman could you show me the example? Maybe I'll be able to find the issue in my own code afterwards.

Comment: @ikkentim Sorry, I did not read you comment until today. I leave my example as answer (I wrote the example one week ago but I was not sure if it could help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it as follows:

```
string mono_string_to_string(MonoString *str)
{
    mono_unichar2 *chl = mono_string_chars(str);
    string out("");
    for (int i = 0; i < mono_string_length(str); i++) {
        out += chl[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Might not be the most beautiful way of doing it, but it works.